# Handling of long living python objects in docker container, remote controll of objects

Tags: python, docker, python-object

I am developing a design which works on top of a docker network topology. It emulates netwrok elements talking to each other using udp packets.
On host the big controller script is executed. It brings up the network of containers with python base image, no other tools added, pip is out of the game.
On the host the main script brings up a topology using `docker network create` and `docker run`. It comes up and ping is working.

Utilizing the benefits of folder sharing, configuration data is already copied to the nodes, they can access it, it is time to make something work in the containers.

The hello.py works already fine, there comes our component_1, who is in this flow the command line interpreter.
I will call it execute_me_remotely.py or execute.py to get shorter.

I can reach this file in the container by

`docker exec execute.py`

execute.py contains a code like this:

```
def parse_and_route_command(passed_params):
    print(f"Node Conrol Call: \n")
    command_string = ""
    parameter_list = []
    i = 0
    for param in passed_params:
        print(f"arg_{i}: {param}")
        parameter_list.append(param)

    command_string = parameter_list[3]
    if "create" == command_string:
        # create an object which will live for a long time
        element_core = object()
    if "start" == command_string:
        # perform a start() call on the object above
        element_core.start()
    if "stop" == command_string:
        element_core.stop()
    if "diag" == command_string:
        element_core.diag()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parse_and_route_command(sys.argv)
```

The host, control script calls it like:

```
docker exec mycontainer execute.py create

# Some time passes

docker exec mycontainer execute.py start
```

element_core is an object which hosts a message loop and is a server application (emulated). element_core is the device logic container and I need a way to control it by docker exec calls in the container.

So far it works good but i abit confused about how to control using `docker exec execute.py`.
I must create an object and let it live in the container so that later I would like to change its states. Start or stop the loop it runs.

***Update:***
I had a good comment from david-maze refering to a database to recreate the object. Yes I use a databasse already to build up this object and this database can more. It is memory in file which with json we can with a single call convert to dictionary and back. I can write into this file from the execute.py script which is called over the network. The received command is interpreted a json key value paar and the long living element core object reads and resets these fields in its loop.

**Update**:
I am coming to a solution using the json file which is passed anyway to this container, `element_core` creation uses it to build up itself. The calls on this script sets a `"command_received":f"{value_from_parameter}"` item in the json.dict. The json file i can reload with no cost and can be used as a shared memory dictionary on the container. `element_core` has to read and reset this item in the json file in its loop.
I move forward now with this, thanks for the inputs, i have learned a lot.
If you think I should consider something or have better ideas, let me know.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Docker or not, variables like this won't outlast their current process, and using a global variable like you show is typically an anti-pattern.  You'll need to arrange to store the object's contents somewhere like a database and reconstruct it when you need it.  This will also help you with very routine container cases like recreating a container on software updates and running multiple replicas of a container to handle load.

Comment: Thanks! "variables like this won't outlast their current proces" is a good statement i have to deal further. Should i simply start a loop in this script to keep objects alive or is there a way to move out from this script not loosing grip on the objects created here? If run a loop here how will I receive the new calls of this script? Will the second call create an other instance with a new spinning loop?

Comment: The created object creates (my_global_singleton_for_a_lifetime ) a message loop, has a complex internal structure to receive and send udp packages. An application. I would like to talk to this application. Can I run it in a subprocess for ever, started from here and then have something to get back to it? This is my entry point to the docker container.  If I continue the execution of this process and build the whole object (i cannot rebuild it by each call as it listens on the network) What will happen when the second docker exec is sent to this container?